# Customisable Image Resizing Server

Tags: images, web-server, caching

I’m looking for a customisable Image Server piece of software that will respond to http requests for images. Here’s our situation. We have tens of customers for whom we provide several web-based products, most of which involve incorporating their images. Typically, a single customer may have 100K images. In our web products the images will be displayed at several different sizes, including thumbnails. So, I want an Image Server that:

- allows my clients to authenticate and upload images
- resizes images based on size specifications in the URL or as GET or POST parameters
- caches resized images is customisable (we have other lesser
  requirements that will inevitably require some custom code –
  preferably using PHP)
- has some admin capability, e.g. to manage
  customer authentication details, manage the cache, delete images etc.
- allows a user to upload data which is used to map “keys” to actual
  image file paths so that requests can simply identify the key
- can be open source or proprietary, free or commercial
- can either be run on
  Windows or Linux (either one works for us)

So long as the Image Server is customisable it will not necessarily have to exhibit all these features as we can code some modifications to make it meet missing requirements.

I have looked at some possibilities but all are quite far from our requirements:
Google App Engine Images API (not customisable enough) and [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/) (does image serving and resizing but doesn’t meet our other requirements).